# Iterating over dictionaries to check for duplicates

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to find matching names in a dictionary.
The user sends a request that looks like this:

```
req= [{"host":"usr1"}, {"host":"usr7"}, {"host":"usr10"}, {"host":"usr11"}, {"host":"usrx...."}, ..../more hosts]
```

Then I check for matches in another dictionary that looks like this:

```
data = [
        {
            "host": "usr1",
            "address": "x"
        },
        {
            "host": "usr2",
            "address": "y"
        },
        {
            "host": "usr3",
            "address": "z"
        }
          .../ more hosts
    ]
```

if there is a match between the request from the user and the database I want to pop that host.
I tried like this:

```
new_static = []
for x, i in zip(data, req):    
    if i['host'] != x['host']:
            new_static.append(x)
    data = new_static
    continue
```

It works, but here a problem occurs if len of the req and the data is not equal, I also tried with double nested loops but with no success.

Comment: What is `sta` in the line `new_static.append(sta)`?

Comment: When you say you wan to "pop that host", what do you mean? Removing it from the database?

Comment: _if there is a match between the request from the user and the database I want to pop that host_ - does this mean you want to remove from user request all host:usr pairs already present in `data`? Are usr unique in `data`, i.e. is it safe to transform the data in a dict e.g. `{'usr1':'x', 'usr2':'y'}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following nested loop solution:

```
req= [{"host":"usr1"}, {"host":"usr7"}, {"host":"usr10"}, {"host":"usr11"}]
data = [
        {
            "host": "usr1",
            "address": "x"
        },
        {
            "host": "usr2",
            "address": "y"
        },
        {
            "host": "usr3",
            "address": "z"
        }]
    
for i in req:    
    for j in data:
        if i["host"] == j["host"]:
            print("Host: ", i["host"])
```

**Output:**

```
Host:  usr1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the objects in your request only contain one key, you can simplify it to a `set` for efficiency. Then, assuming you want to filter the elements of `data` that have a `host` not in `req`, this can be accomplished by:

```py
hosts_request = set(el['host'] for el in req)
filtered_data = [entry for entry in data if entry['host'] not in hosts_request]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
sinmple = [e["host"] for e in data]
for r in req:
    if r["host"] in simple:
        pass
        # do something with the duplicat
```